# Convert word document with headers in xml structure

Tags: c#, xml, docx, doc

I'm a student civil engineering (architecture) in Ghent, Belgium.
For my scription, I'm developing a tool able to generate building specifications.

Building specifications are frequently provided in .DOC(X)-format but my tool works with XML-structures.

Can someone help me to convert a doc level with a table content (headers) to an XML structure? 
I have found topics for this conversion, but always end up with an enormous XML filled with all possible information (ID's, colors etc..) but I only need the text itself. The text is already structured in levels with headings.

For example:
DOCX:

```
(header 1) 00. GENERAL CHAPTER
(header 2) 00.10.   PROJECT INFORMATION
(header 3) BUILDING SITE
The building is on a hill
(header 3) CLIENT
Mr Jack Overflow
```

Converted into:

```
<level1 name="00. GENERAL CHAPTER">
<level2 name="00.10.    PROJECT INFORMATION">
<level3 name="BUILDING SITE">
<Content>The building is on a hill</Content>
</level3>
<level3 name="CLIENT">
<Content>Mr Jack Overflow</Content>
</level3>
</level2>
</level1>
```

The tool is being developed in C# within Visual Studio Community using a Windows Forms Application

Help or just a reference to a good topic will be appreciated deeply!

Comment: If your goal is to start from an unmodified .docx, you'll have to deal with an intermediate bloated Xml. To produce the desired output you then can apply an Xsl transformation. If your output Xml schema isn't already fixed it could do with a generic root other than `<level1>` because you'll be in trouble if you encounter more than exactly one `header 1`. Using elements including structure and/or order in their name is also not recommended because it will make schema validation a nightmare.